# Convert list df (with multiple columns) to numeric

Tags: r

I have a df below:

```
view(fds)

   #1 #2 #3 #4
1# 1  3  4  2
2# 4  5  3  2
3# 2  5  3  1
4# 3  5  1  3
```

I want to `fds.sum <- rowSums(fds)` but I get an "Error in rowSums(fds) : 'x' must be numeric"... Then, when I try `fds.mun <- as.numeric(fds)`, I get an "Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'"...

I have tried `fds.num <- lapply(fds, as.numeric)` but that gives me:

```
fds.num  list[4]        List of Length 4
 1#      double[101]    1 4 2 3
 2#      double[101]    3 5 5 5
 3#      double[101]    4 3 3 1
 4#      double[101]    2 2 1 3
```

I just want a sum of my rows in a new column such that:

```
   #1 #2 #3 #4 sum
1# 1  3  4  2  10
2# 4  5  3  2  14
3# 2  5  3  1  11
4# 3  5  1  3  12
```

Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to use the OP's code, just `Reduce` with `+`

```
fds$sum <- Reduce(`+`, lapply(fds, as.numeric) )
```

---

Or after converting to `numeric`, bind them as a `matrix` or update the original data

```
fds[] <- lapply(fds, as.numeric)
fds$sum <- rowSums(fds, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Or it can be done on the fly with `sapply`

```
fds$sum <- rowSums(sapply(fds, as.numeric))
```

Or even without doing `as.numeric`, can be automated with `type.convert`

```
fds$sum <- rowSums(type.convert(fds, as.is = TRUE))
```

---

The `error` showed in OP's code is a a result of applying `rowSums` directly on a `list` as `lapply` always returns a `list`